# Downloading 32 Bit printer drivers for sharing on LAN

Tags: windows-7, drivers, network-shares, home-sharing

I have a Windows 7 64 Bit machine with two printers connected to it, an HP OfficeJet J3680 and a HP Deskjet 5150. I shared both printers on the LAN, and it worked with no issues.

The thing is that when sharing, you can add the drivers to the system for the clients to download, in this case only 64 Bit is available. For 32 Bit we need to download it from HP.com.

The problem here is that the website says that there is nothing to download, as the drivers are provided with Windows 7. This is true for 64 Bit, but not 32 Bit.

How can I get both drivers?

Answer (score 0):

For the OfficeJet J3680, there is a driver on the HP site:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-79585-2&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=3441026&sw_lang= (full featured)

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-79587-2&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=3441026&sw_lang= (basic features)

For the Deskjet 5150, use the Windows 7 OfficeJet 5100 driver, it will work fine.

[image]